# Breakpoints in .net core library will not be hit when debugging consuming WinForms app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I created a sample to reproduce my issue at work, and the problem is there.
I have a Solution with a WinForms project, targeting .NET framework 4.7, and a .NET Core library, targint .NET Core 2 (tried the 4.6.1 / .Net Standard 2.0 combination as well, same)

**Form1.cs looks like:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Helper.Method1(100).ToString());
    }
}
```

**Library code:**

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static int Method1(int a)
    {
        a = a + 1;

        return a; //breakpoint here
    }

}
```

I can't have Visual Studio hit the breakpoint in Helper, from the .net core library (in neither one of the combinations - .net framework vs .net core NOR .net framework (4.6.1) vs .net standard (2.0))

**What am I missing ?**

I found a [Scott Hanselman's post on this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceANETCoreLibraryInWinFormsOrNETStandardExplained.aspx), but, if I got him right, what is required is that the library does not taget a specific framework rather one of the .NET standards (and that the consuming project targeting framework complies with that standard). I seem to be doing that.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking: Is the code not breaking? Or are you not hitting the Helper class's Method1 code when single stepping? Do you have a solid red circle on the breakpoint line before running?

Comment: @Jazimov: No solid red circle (what "breakpoint will not be hit" means, in VS), that was the problem. JBSregath's trick did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to hit breakpoints set within Visual Studio, it needs to have information files (for instance the .pdb files you see within the ./bin/Debug directory) that help Visual Studio to know where exceptions occur, gather information on variable values, and way more stuff.

The amount of information that is generated in addition to the actual application/library files can be set accordingly here:
Go to Project > Properties > Build > Advanced (button at bottom) > Debugging information.

Note: this is **not** solution wide setting, it needs to be set for each project.
For more information on what the selectable settings mean: [Advanced Build Settings Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/advanced-build-settings-dialog-box-csharp?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solutions are the hardest to find (hidden behind buttons/menu's). Take care! ;)

Comment: What did the "check" reveal? Can you share the specifics so others can learn from what you discovered?

Comment: @Jazimov: revealed JBSregath's answer is the solution.

Comment: That's not helpful at all. It might have helped you, but no one can know from his answer what you specifically found that helped. If you don't want to share, I can't force you, but no sharing is not within the spirit of SO.

Comment: @Jazimov I edited my answer to provide additional information, now it is not just a 'check this setting' answer.